# Having trouble understanding recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I was doing the first recursion exercise on this here: http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/16-recursion/

I followed the obvious hint and made this:

```
def countup(n):
  if n == 0:
    print('Blastoff!')
  else:
    countup(n - 1)
    print(n)
```

So the code basically counts up from 0(blastoff) to n. I just don't understand how it works - i looked in the visualiser and it goes through countup(n) to countup(0) at which point it print's off 'Blastoff', all good. After this it sort of...stays in the else loop and starts printing out the previous n values..why would it do this. Does it store the n values for some reason and even if it does how does this codes mechanism work exactly? Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Recursion: see *recursion*. The `countup()` function call eventually returns. To whatever called it..

Comment: Try to reverse the `countup(n-1)` and `print(n)` lines. Debug, see that you understand it. Then reverse it back.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting. It's a legitimate question from someone who is starting to code. It's not a "do my homework" type of question.

Comment: I agree with @Pedro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time `countup()` calls itself, it'll eventually return to that same point where it called. The next line will then print `n`, as it was *during that function call*.

And each time you call a function, all its names are created anew, they are *local*. As such, each time you call `countup()` you have a local, independent value for `n`.

Essentially you create a chain of `countup()` calls:

- `countup(2)`: `n` is `2`, not `0`, so the `else` branch is executed, calls `countup(1)`

  - `countup(1)`: `n` is `1`, not `0`, so the `else` branch is executed, calls `countup(0)`

    - `countup(0)`: `n` is `0`, print `Blastoff!!`, and the function returns

    The `countup(0)` call returned, next line prints `n`, still 1 in this call. Next, the function returns.

  The `countup(1)` call returned, next line prints `n`, still 2 in this call. Next, the function returns.

Comment: Wasn't me who down voted, I thought your answer was incredibly helpful - thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It uses recursion to print the numbers.
The best way to understand this is by an example:

```
countup(3)
  countup(2)
    countup(1)
      countup(0)
        n == 0
        print('Blastoff!')
    print (1)
  print(2)
print(3)
```

Each time the function is called, it calles the same function with `n-1`, until `n==0`. At this point, it begins printing numbers as shown.

Comment: Thank you! that made it a lot easier to understand, i'm finding recursion to be very tricky haha.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the variant:

```
def countup(n):
  if n == 0:
    print('Blastoff!')
  else:
    print(n, end=', ')
    countup(n - 1)
       # print(n, end=', ')    reverse
```

Prints:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1, Blastoff!
```

Vs reverse the order of the print with the recursive call:

```
def countup(n):
  if n == 0:
    print('Blastoff!')
  else:
        # print(n, end=', ')    reverse  
    countup(n - 1)
    print(n, end=', ')
```

Prints:

```
Blastoff!
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

You can now see that with the recursive call of `countup(n - 1)` before the `print(n, end=', ')`, the function must go all the way to the end test of  `if n == 0:` before any print is encountered.

Once the condition of `if n == 0:` is met, then the entire call chain is unwound printing the arguments to `countup` in the reverse order.

Consider as another classic recursive example reversing a string:

```
def rrev(s):
    if s == "":
        return s
    else:
        return rrev(s[1:]) + s[0]
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
def rrev(s):
    return rrev(s[1:]) + s[0] if s else s
```

Comment: yeah it makes sense now, the 'previous' function hasn't actually terminated so it comes back to it where it left off (right before the print(n), thanks.